# HVR-850 sound stutter on Ubuntu and Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, video-capture-card

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit in its own partitions on my AMD dual-core Athlon.  It works well, except for the sound from my USB television - a Hauppauge HVR-850 when I use TVtime.  There is a constant stutter which makes the dialog almost unintelligible.  All other sound sources work perfectly (e.g. VLC playing movies, youtube through the web, etc).

I've tried various things that turned up on searches for this problem but nothing works.  I tried MeTV, which wouldn't even recognize the device, and MythTV which put me down the 'rabbit-hole' dealing with MySQL issues and missing triggerMaps - whatever those are - despite recognizing the device.

The only solution that seemed to partially work was to pipe outputs through arecord and aplay.  Seems a bit Rube-Goldberg-ish just to use the app. That resulted in audio/video sync problems.

I also tried Xubuntu, which of course has the same issue.  Kubuntu is unstable on my machine.

Does anyone have any ideas on a nifty fix? 
Thank you.

Edit:
The `load-module module-loopback` was added to /etc/pulse/default.pa

Comment: I'll answer my own question.   After muddling around for a long time, I finally found the fix:   "load-module module-loopback".